What is the proper way to typehint a class decorator?
I have this class decorator from here: Python bind Dataclass and TypedDict (Inherit Dataclass from TypedDict) which makes a dataclass inherit TypedDict by injecting the TypedDict into the dataclass.
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypedDict, Callable

def inject_fields(parent) -> Callable:
    def doit(cls):
        cls.__annotations__ = parent.__annotations__ | cls.__annotations__
        return cls
    return doit


# and then:


class UserDB(TypedDict):
    id: int

@dataclass
@injectfields(UserDB)
class UserDC:
    # "id: int" is injected from `TypedDict`
    name: str

What would be the proper way to typehint the function inject_fields? In this case type(parent) == UserDB and type(cls) == UserDC, but they can't be referenced directly in inject_fields, since both classes are defined after defining inject_fields.
I have been trying to read up on declaring decorators here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators but the most correct way to go about it is not very clear to me.

A nice way of doing it if you are on python 3.12 is:
from typing import Any, Callable

def inject_fields[P: TypedDict, C: Any](parent: type[P]) -> Callable[[type[C]], type[C]]:
    def doit(cls: type[C]) -> type[C]:
        cls.__annotations__ = parent.__annotations__ | cls.__annotations__
        return cls
    return doit

It basically creates two typevars, P and C (for parent and child), where P's upper bound is TypedDict, that means that it accepts only TypedDict or subclasses. The type[P] is used because P would represent an object of TypedDict and we want the type (so basically, instead of calling: @inject_fields(UserDB()) we can use @inject_fields(UserDB))
